# usage of "and" in stead of "comma"

Tags: punctuation

> To  be  exact,  it  takes  365  days,  5  hours,  48 minutes  and  46  seconds.  For  a  long  time  people  did  not  add  **these  extra  hours  and  minutes  and seconds.** It  was  like  using  a  watch  that  runs  slow.

I am so confused with the usage of **and** in"extra hours and minutes and seconds." I think,according to comma rules, it should be **these extra hours, minutes and seconds**.

Does "and" use to leave out the repeated word "extra"?

Answer (score 1):

You can make any list by stringing conjunctions together.

> "For my team I choose Mary and Ron and Emily and Jane, but you can have Pete and Caroline and Alan."

That is an expanded way of saying

> "For my team I choose Mary, Ron, Emily, and Jane, but you can have Pete, Caroline, and Alan."

They are simply different ways of saying the same thing. Note that the first example is for most purposes needlessly verbose. But sometimes you may wish to emphasize what you are saying by stressing the conjunctions to underscore the additive nature of the list items.

> > "For my team I choose Mary **and** Ron **and** Emily **and** Jane, but you can have Pete **and** Caroline **and** Alan."

That's not the only to emphasize them, but it's a valid and grammatical way to do so.